# How to omit regex pattern filter chars?

Tags: regex, swift, pattern-matching

I'm using such way of regEx in Swift 3

```
let reg = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: .CaseInsensitive)
let matches = reg.matchesInString(text, options: NSMatchingOptions.WithTransparentBounds, range: NSMakeRange(0, text.characters.count))
```

Then I'm using such pattern as "`<hh>(.*?)</hh>`"
Then I'm getting matches which contains "`<hh>`" in it's start and "`</hh>`" in it's finish. How to get only value between them?

Comment: Remove tags by hands, pretty easy

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now, but try something along the lines of:

```
for match in matches {
    let matchRange = match.rangeAtIndex(1)
    let substring = text.substringWithRange(matchRange)
    //do something with your subscring
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding a **removingTagLength** parameter to the function I use for finding regex matches and just using this param in range when calling **substringWithRange**

```
nsText.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(match.range.location + removingTagLength, match.range.length - (removingTagLength > 0 ? removingTagLength + 1 : 0)))
```

Comment: You should break that statement up, it's pretty long.